# Confusion about "this" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In the code below why

```
alert(window.concatenateAandB());
```

works fine and displays **"Hello world"**? I know based on the tip from http://java.dzone.com/articles/javascript-java-developers this refers to current object which is "window" but again I dont get it! I am from Java background and thought the right version would have to be

```
window.Simple.concatenateAandB()
```

can anyone helped me out here?

```
function Simple(a, b) {
  var propertyA = a;
  var propertyB = b;

  this.concatenateAandB = function() {
    return propertyA + propertyB;
  }

}

Simple("Hello ","world")

alert(window.concatenateAandB());
```

Comment: The first time you call `Simple`, you create a method of `this`, which is `window` in non strict mode. Then `window.concatenateAandB` will be that function.

Comment: Regarding how `window.concatenateAandB()` is able to alert `"Hello world"`, see [**How do JavaScript closures work?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) Note: Closures are independent of `this`. Your snippet just uses them together.